# Azure Sql database AAD user not getting created

Tags: azure-sql-database, active-directory

I need to create an AAD user for a Windows security group that was recently synchronised with Azure AD. This security group has spaces in its name.

I am using the below SQL script but it keeps failing because of the spaces:

```
Create user [security group name@xyz.com] from external provider;
```

If I look for this group under active directory in portal, I don’t see its corresponding UPN. Does it mean that all accounts sourced from on-premise do not contain UPN?

Comment: [<domainname>\<loginname>] cannot be used while creating the AAD user for a azure database

Comment: What is the exact error? Are you sure that your group type is Mail enabled security?

Comment: How do you provide access to a security group in Sql azure database?